# Awk command to perform action on lines excluding 1st and last

Tags: unix, awk

I have multiple MS excel files in csv format in a particular directory.
I want to update the value of one particular column in all the rows of the csv files.

Also, the action should not be operated on 1st and last line.
So far I have come up with below code for one row:

```
awk -F, 'NR>2{$2=300;}1' OFS=, test.csv
```

But i am facing difficulty in excluding the last line.
Also, i need to perform the same for all the files in the directory.

So far tried the below but not able to succeed to replace that string value using awk.
1)

[image]

2)

[image: a]

Answer (score 3):

This may do:

```
awk -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>1{$2=300;t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test.csv
```

Comment: I am trying to use the below but getting error: 

awk -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>1{$3='ops_dat<dbms=TD::instance=idw-prod>';t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test1.csv "-sh: dbms=TD::instance=idw-prod: No such file or directory"

Comment: @user3901666 Since `awk` is wrapped by single quotes, you can not use single quote within `awk`, so this will fail `$3='ops_da...`.  Do a google search on how to use single quote in `awk` search.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
1,a,b
2,c,d
3,e,f

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1{print (NR>2 ? chgd : orig)} {orig=$0; $2=300; chgd=$0} END{print orig}' file
1,a,b
2,300,d
3,e,f
```

Comment: I am trying to use the below but getting error:
awk -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>1{$3='ops_dat<dbms=TD::instance=idw-prod>';t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test1.csv

"-sh: dbms=TD::instance=idw-prod: No such file or directory"

Comment: You should ask whoever suggested that script about any errors you get trying to execute it.

Comment: Yes, i did. I tried your script as well but that also wont work for the cases i have mentioned.

Comment: You asked a question and I answered it. If you have a new question then feel free to post it

Comment: Thanks Ed.  Yeah sure i will.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the script a bit by reading the file twice:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {c=NR;next} !(FNR==1||FNR==c){$2=200} 1' file file
```

This uses the `NR==FNR` section merely to count lines, giving you a simple expression for determining whether to update the field in question.

And if you have GNU awk available, you might save a few CPU cycles by not reassigning the `c` variable for every line, using something like this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ENDFILE {c=FNR} NR==FNR{next} !(FNR==1||FNR==c){$2=200} 1' file file
```

This still reads the file twice, but assigns `c` only after each file is read.

If you want, you can emulate the ENDFILE condition in non-GNU awk using `NR>FNR && FNR==1` if you only have two files, then set `c=NR-1`. It won't perform as well.

I haven't tested the speed difference between these two, but I suspect it would be negligible except in cases of truly obscenely large files.

Comment: Good idea. Or more efficiently if your file is huge: `awk -v c="$(wc -l < file)" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} (NR>1) && (NR<c){$2=200} 1' file` (the switch to positive logic is just my preference, it's the `wc` that'll improve performance).
`

Comment: @ghoti I tried using below:----
awk -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>2{$3='ops_dat\<dbms=Teradata::instance=idw-prod\>';t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test1.csv
-----
Still getting error.

Comment: @user3901666, for that solution perhaps you should ask Jotne. If you're getting an error, perhaps you could update your question to include details of the attempt, along with the error. Formatting is much better in the question than it is in comments. Oh, and mind your quotes. From here it looks as if you're trying to include single quotes within a single-quoted string, which of course won't work.

Comment: Yeah, i searched google as well but i couldn't find any clear solution for the same.

Comment: Per your update, it's as I suggested -- you should switch to double quotes for the assignment within the single-quoted script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I got to make it work. Below is the command:

awk -v sq="" -F, 't{print t} {a=t=$0} NR>2{$3=sq"ops_data"sq;t=$0} END {print a}' OFS=, test1.csv